# Error : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I am plotting a scatter plot with a line of best fit from a csv dataset im calling srh_study using the code below. When I run the code chunk just in R it works fine, but when I try to knit it, I get that Error message.

```
srh_N <- 
  ggplot(data = srh_study, aes(x = N, y = srh)) +
  geom_point(colour='black', alpha = 0.5, size= 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se =FALSE)
  labs(x = "Score of N", y = "Self Rated Health")
```

Comment: try `as.numeric()` on the x and y variables.  As you have not provided sample data, it is hard to test issues with your data.  You can use `dput(head(srh_study))` and post the output to your question.

Comment: Make sure you have `library(ggplot2)` in your knitr document, also don't forget the `+` inbetween `geom_smooth()` and `labs()`. This sounds like a syntax error somewhere... perhaps post the whole code chunk if you need more help.